# Merging pandas dataframes using date as index

Tags: python, merge, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to merge two dataframes (call them df1 and df2) of different lengths which are both indexed by their dates.  The longer of the dfs (df1) has all the dates listed in the shorter of the two (df2).  I've tried to combine them using the following command: `merged = df2.merge(df1, on='Date')`, however I get the following errors which I don't understand when I try to do so.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-47-e8d3e1ec920d> in <module>()
----> 1 merged = df2.merge(df1, on='Date')

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.pyc in merge(self, right, how, on, left_on, right_on, left_index, right_index, sort, suffixes, copy)
  3630                      left_on=left_on, right_on=right_on,
  3631                      left_index=left_index, right_index=right_index, sort=sort,
-> 3632                      suffixes=suffixes, copy=copy)
  3633 
  3634     #----------------------------------------------------------------------

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/tools/merge.pyc in merge(left, right, how, on, left_on, right_on, left_index, right_index, sort, suffixes, copy)
    37                          right_on=right_on, left_index=left_index,
    38                          right_index=right_index, sort=sort, suffixes=suffixes,
---> 39                          copy=copy)
    40     return op.get_result()
    41 if __debug__:

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/tools/merge.pyc in __init__(self, left, right, how, on, left_on, right_on, axis, left_index, right_index, sort, suffixes, copy)
    181         (self.left_join_keys,
    182          self.right_join_keys,
--> 183          self.join_names) = self._get_merge_keys()
    184 
    185     def get_result(self):

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/tools/merge.pyc in _get_merge_keys(self)
    324                 else:
    325                     if not is_rkey(rk):
--> 326                         right_keys.append(right[rk].values)
    327                         if lk == rk:
    328                             # avoid key upcast in corner case (length-0)

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.pyc in __getitem__(self, key)
  1656             return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
  1657         else:
-> 1658             return self._getitem_column(key)
  1659 
  1660     def _getitem_column(self, key):

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.pyc in _getitem_column(self, key)
  1663         # get column
  1664         if self.columns.is_unique:
-> 1665             return self._get_item_cache(key)
  1666 
  1667         # duplicate columns & possible reduce dimensionaility

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.pyc in _get_item_cache(self, item)
  1003         res = cache.get(item)
  1004         if res is None:
-> 1005             values = self._data.get(item)
  1006             res = self._box_item_values(item, values)
  1007             cache[item] = res

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/internals.pyc in get(self, item)
  2872                 return self.get_for_nan_indexer(indexer)
  2873 
-> 2874             _, block = self._find_block(item)
  2875             return block.get(item)
  2876         else:

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/internals.pyc in _find_block(self, item)
  3184 
  3185     def _find_block(self, item):
-> 3186         self._check_have(item)
  3187         for i, block in enumerate(self.blocks):
  3188             if item in block:

/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/internals.pyc in _check_have(self, item)
  3191     def _check_have(self, item):
  3192         if item not in self.items:
-> 3193             raise KeyError('no item named %s' % com.pprint_thing(item))
  3194 
  3195     def reindex_axis(self, new_axis, indexer=None, method=None, axis=0,

KeyError: u'no item named Date'
```

I've also tried dropping the `on='Date'` as both are already indexed by the date but the result seems the same. Any idea as to where I might be going wrong?

Comment: Use `join` instead of `merge`; it merges on indexes by default.

Comment: @KarlD.  Thanks for the response!  So if I'm understanding correctly, it should look like this: `merged = df2.join(df1)`?

Comment: @KarlD. I gave it a try and got [these errors](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/11993667/joined). Unfortunately I don't have any idea what they imply.

Comment: My suggestion is you print out part of your actually dataframes and print out your `df1.info()` and `df2.info()` so we can have a better sense of what is actually going on.

Comment: Looking at your error messages it looks like you have overlapping column names; add something like the `rsuffix='_y'` option to join.

Comment: @KarlD.  You're right!  The errors ended up being fixed by changing the column names with`resuffix='_y'`.  Feel free to write up the comment in an answer if you'd like some points for it.  Thanks much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it is most naturally to use `join` because it merges on indexes by default. So something like the following:

```
merged = df2.join(df1,rsuffix='_y')
```

Add the `rsuffix='_y'` because you have common column names in both dataframes.