# pandas merge and fill a dataframe with summary data

Tags: python, pandas, merge

Supposing I have a data frame as follows:

```
frameA = pandas.DataFrame(dict(title=['a','a','a','b','b','b'],value=[1,2,3,4,5,6]))
frameB = pd.DataFrame(dict(title=['a','b'],value=[10,20]))
```

`frameA` looks like

```
  title  value
0     a      1
1     a      2
2     a      3
3     b      4
4     b      5
5     b      6
```

and frameB looks like

```
  title  value
0     a     10
1     b     20
```

I'd like to do some kind of merge or join so that I get

```
   title  value value2
    a      1      10
    a      2      10
    a      3      10
    b      4      20
    b      5      20
    b      6      20
```

I tried 
`pd.concat([frameA,frameB],axis=1)`
and `frameA.merge(frameB)`
and `frameA.apply(lambda x: frameB[x.title])`

None of which work. I'm sure there is a really obvious way but I just cant seem to find it at the moment. Thanks

========================================

and right after I posted this I came across

[Merging pandas dataframes using date as index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23281397/merging-pandas-dataframes-using-date-as-index?rq=1) seems to show one way. Are there any others?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is a left join.
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/merging.html

```
pd.merge(frameA,frameB,on='title',how='left')
```

Out:

```
  title  value_x  value_y
0     a        1       10
1     a        2       10
2     a        3       10
3     b        4       20
4     b        5       20
5     b        6       20
```

Answer (score 3):

Other way of merging :

frameA.merge(frameB,on ='title', how ='left')

```
  title  value_x  value_y
0   a     1        10
1   a     2        10
2   a     3        10
3   b     4        20
4   b     5        20
5   b     6        20
```

Answer (score 1):

A faster method that doesn't involve renaming/dropping columns is to set the index of frameB to `title` and call [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html#pandas.Series.map) on frameA passing in the other df and passing a series. This will perform a lookup using the title values and return the values that match:

```
In [85]:

frameB.set_index('title', inplace=True)
frameA['value2'] = frameA['title'].map(frameB['value'])
frameA
Out[85]:
  title  value  value2
0     a      1      10
1     a      2      10
2     a      3      10
3     b      4      20
4     b      5      20
5     b      6      20
```

If we compare the performance of merging against map, we can see that map is much faster nearly 5X faster:

```
In [70]:

%timeit pd.merge(frameA,frameB,on='title',how='left')
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.42 ms per loop
In [83]:

frameB.set_index('title', inplace=True)
%timeit frameA['value2'] = frameA['title'].map(frameB['value'])
1000 loops, best of 3: 286 µs per loop
```